# Lookaround regex to evaluate both sides?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Ok, I have a pretty tricky regex problem.

I need to match and replace the + signs in the following strings with whitespace, thus the strings on the left must become the strings on the right.

```
1: word+word   =  word word
2: word+++word =  word + word
3: word.+word  =  word. word
4: word,+word  =  word, word
```

I've managed to nail most of 'em with this, which checks for strings before and after plus signs:

```
(?<=[\w\.,])\+(?=[\w])
```

However, I can only nail one set of the adjacent plus signs in (2) at a time:

```
(?<=[\w\.,\+])\+(?=[\w]) // gets the left plus sign
2: word+++word =  word++ word

(?<=[\w\.,])\+(?=[\w\+]) // gets the right plus sign
2: word+++word =  word ++word
```

In my current regex be-frazzled state, I'm wondering if I need to wrap the pattern in a larger condition, or if I need to implement an either or pattern in the lookarounds. Any regex mavens out there care to give this a whirl?

Comment: What about `foo++++bar++++++baz`?

Comment: What's the programming language you are using? Not every flavor supports lookaround.

Comment: Since you are having problem with your regex, which means that your regex might not be right, why not write in ordinary words what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Felix - PHP, it's good to go

Comment: @sunwukung: Yes, kind of. Only fixed sized lookbehinds ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work on your examples:

```
(?<!\+)\+|\+(?!\+)
```

Replace that with spaces.

Example:

```
perl -E "$_='a+b++a+++b++++c+++++d'; s/(?<!\+)\+|\+(?!\+)/ /g; say"
```

Outputs:

```
a b  a + b ++ c +++ d
```